# Is it possible to create a Vorpal application which the command's output goes directly to the terminal, instead of it's own shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vorpal.js

When you create [Vorpal](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) application, at least from what I see in the docs, it creates it's own shell. First, you enter that shell, and then you start executing commands. Like this:

```
user@computer: quotr
quotr$
quotr$ snapshot
You triggered `snapshot`.
quotr$
```

In the above example, the `snapshot` command is being executed "inside" the Vorpal shell. It's output doesn't go directly to the terminal.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
user@computer: quotr snapshot
You triggered `snapshot`.
user@computer:
```

How can I achieve that with Vorpal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `vorpal.parse` method, which will parse the arguments passed into Vorpal and execute them.

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal
  .command('snapshot')
  .action(function (args, cb) {
    this.log('You triggered `snapshot`.');
    cb();
  });

vorpal.parse(process.argv);
```

You can have the app exit after completing the command simply by omitting `vorpal.show()`. Because there is no prompt, Node realizes there is nothing left to do, and the process will exit naturally.

Comment: The code you posted works, but not, as you say, because you emitted show(). It works because you failed to call the callback at the end of the action. If you add `cb()` in the action, you'll stay in vorpal. Even with the code you posted, if the argument given at the command line is anything other than `snapshot`, it will stay in vorpal.

Comment: I just want to add - to use this as a solution, you'd have to check for `process.argv` in every single command. There's gotta be a better way to do this.

Comment: That was just a typo --- this should exit. Will check out.